# How to include text out of tag inside the tag. Python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I faced a problem while parsing XML using BeautifulSoap and Python.

For example part of XML content provided below:

```
xml = '''<line b="498" baseline="488" l="520" r="1248" t="456">
     <formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">
       $
      <price appendorder="10" class="extraction-tag" confidence="1/1" data-original-title="Price" data-toggle="tooltip" data-value="25.00" style="background-color: rgb(192, 185, 178);" tagorder="10">
       25.00
      </price>
      .
     </formatting>
    </line>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml-xml")
tag = soup.price
tag['data-value'] = "$25.00"
tag.string = "$25.00"
outside_tag_str = str(tag.find_parent())
new_outside_tag_str = outside_tag_str.replace("$<", "<")
print(new_outside_tag_str)


#prints: <formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">
      $
      <price appendorder="10" class="extraction-tag" confidence="1/1" data-original-title="Price" data-toggle="tooltip" data-value="$25.00" style="background-color: rgb(192, 185, 178);" tagorder="10">$25.00</price>
      .
     </formatting>
```

As you can see, I want to include dollar sign into  tag, but my code returns dollar sing inside and outside the tag. What I am doing wrong? I want to be returned:

```
<formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">
  <price appendorder="10" class="extraction-tag" confidence="1/1" data-original-title="Price" data-toggle="tooltip" data-value="$25.00" style="background-color: rgb(192, 185, 178);" tagorder="10">$25.00</price>
  .
 </formatting>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `new_outside_tag_str = outside_tag_str.replace("$<", "<")` looks fishhyy

Comment: I am a new one with python, so if you point out the error I will be grateful

Comment: No worries. see if the answer posted below helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace this**:

```
new_outside_tag_str = outside_tag_str.replace("$<", "<")
```

**with this**:

```
new_outside_tag_str = outside_tag_str.replace(" $", "")
```

**Why?**

Because you need to replace exactly `$` ( space followed by dollar sign) with an empty string, previously you were aiming for an invalid string.

**Hence**:

```
xml = '''<line b="498" baseline="488" l="520" r="1248" t="456">
     <formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">
       $
      <price appendorder="10" class="extraction-tag" confidence="1/1" data-original-title="Price" data-toggle="tooltip" data-value="25.00" style="background-color: rgb(192, 185, 178);" tagorder="10">
       25.00
      </price>
      .
     </formatting>
    </line>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml-xml")
tag = soup.price
tag['data-value'] = "$25.00"
tag.string = "$25.00"
outside_tag_str = str(tag.find_parent())
new_outside_tag_str = outside_tag_str.replace(" $", "")
print(new_outside_tag_str)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
<formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates">

      <price appendorder="10" class="extraction-tag" confidence="1/1" data-original-title="Price" data-toggle="tooltip" data-value="$25.00" style="background-color: rgb(192, 185, 178);" tagorder="10">$25.00</price>
      .
     </formatting>
```